# WIth pushout each orthogonality class is an injectivity class

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, diagram-chasing, locally-presentable-categories

I cannot see how follows the equality
$\cal M^{\bot}=M^*$-Inj below: (both inclusions are wanted)

[image]

where

$X \in {\cal H}^\bot \iff \forall f\in{\cal H}: \mathrm{Hom}(f,X)$ bijective

and

$X \in {\cal H}$-Inj $\iff \forall f\in{\cal H}: \mathrm{Hom}(f,X)$ surjective

Comment: What is the relationship of $h$ in your $\forall h$ with the r.h.s. of $\Longleftrightarrow$ ? Its only ocurrence is within the quantification scope and is not present after it. Something must be wrong? Perhaps $f$ and $h$ are the **same** arrows?

Comment: yes, it should be 'f' everywhere. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite straightforward:

($\subseteq$) Let $X\in {\cal M}^\bot$.
Because ${\cal M}^\bot \subseteq {\cal M}$-Inj, we only need to check that
$X$ is injective w.r.t. all the $m^*$. So let $f\colon A^* \to X$.

(1) the equation $f\circ p_1\circ m = f\circ p_2\circ m$ forces
$f\circ p_1 = f\circ p_2$ because both maps extend $f\circ p_1\circ m$
along $m$.

(2) Let $h=f\circ p_1=f\circ p_2$.
For $i=1,2$ the equations $h \circ m^* \circ p_i = h = f \circ p_i$
force $h \circ m^* = f$ because of the universal property of the pushout.

Therefore $h$ indeed extends $f$ along $m^*$.

($\supseteq$) Let $X\in {\cal M}^*$-Inj. Given $f\colon A \to X$, we already
know that $f$ can be extended along $m$ because $X\in {\cal M}$-Inj.
So we only need to check that such an extension is unique.

Suppose $h_1,h_2\colon A\to X$ are two maps with $q_1\circ m = f = q_2\circ m$.
Then the pushout gives a unique map $g\colon A^*\to X$ with
$g\circ p_i = q_i$ ($i=1,2$). Let $h\colon A'\to X$ be an extension of $g$
along $m^*$, i.e. $h\circ m^* = g$. Then

$$q_1 = g \circ p_1 = h\circ m^* \circ p_1 = h = h\circ m^* \circ p_2 = g \circ p_2 = q_2$$

Comment: Your notation is just beautiful.